# ubuntu server minimal installation?

Tags: server, ubuntu-minimal

Is there a ubuntu server minimal installation? or is just 4gb/6gb base of installation without the packages, other feature installation?

Answer (score 0):

There is the minimal CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD, only ~40 MB. This allows you to install a minimal system, and select different setups.

Comment: yes, i have tried it, but when i installed using the minimal iso after installation it says 4gb installation on the virtual hard disk.. i'm using hyper-v for virtualization.. i will try again..

Comment: or it is just plane 4gb base installation?

Comment: 40 mb file turns into 4gb?

Comment: That the size of the harddisk is 4 GB, is something you choose when you allocate the virtual disk to the vm. Normally the installer will use wht are available. In a terminal, run 'df -h' and see how much of your disk is used for / (root) and other filesystems.

Comment: is there a less installation of ubuntu server? like, without the packages and softwares?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Minimal results in the same files being installed on the drive as the standard installation; it simply downloads the files rather than including them in the ISO.

You may want to consider using [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) instead. It uses the same core system as standard Ubuntu, but stripped down and with a more lightweight desktop environment.

Comment: does it have the same bash with the ubuntu distros?

Comment: yes, it has the same shell environment is compatible with any program written for the Ubuntu environment

Comment: it saids here that lubuntu is an operating system, not a server.. (FYI sorry i am a beginner, just getting started)

Comment: All servers use an operating system. 
The "server" version of  an operating system simply means that it doesn't have a graphical interface (purely a shell interface).
You can download the server version of Lubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO

Comment: okay i will try.. thank you for replying, i will let you know if it works ^_^

Comment: do lubuntu has the same repositories from ubuntu repositories?

Comment: yes.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_vs_Ubuntu

Comment: i have tested and installed lubuntu, and it is still 4gb+ in complete installation, i thought this was a lightweight ubuntu variant distro,..

Comment: why is anyone not using lubuntu as a server? purely it has the same core and it has the same repo...

Comment: there is no lubuntu server version download link, the link that you have given to me..